# How to create a reusable ig-grid

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I've searched for an example but have not been able to find one. My goal is to reuse the CreateGrid method by passing in different variables. My problem is that I am not able to dynamically set the columns in the grid. I cannot figure out how to pass the columns variable. If anyone knows please submit an example or direct me to an example. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks...

Example:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {      
        var blnAuto = false;


        var dogs = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DogList));
        var gridA = "#gridDog";
        var dogColumns =  '{ key: "Type", headerText: "Type", dataType: "string", width: "50%"},{ key: "Name", headerText: "Name", dataType: "string", width: "50%" }'

        CreateGrid(dogs, gridA, blnAuto,  dogColumns);

        var cars = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CarList));
        var  gridB = "#gridCar";
        var carColumns =  '{ key: "Make", headerText: "Make", dataType: "string", width: "34%"},{ key: "Model", headerText: "Model", dataType: "string", width: "33%" }, { key: "Year", headerText: "Year", dataType: "string", width: "33%"}'

        CreateGrid(cars, gridB, blnAuto, carColumns)           
    })



    function CreateGrid(data, grid, autoGen, columnVariable)
    {
        var bln = false;


            $(grid).igGrid({
                width: "100%",
                dataSource: data,
                dataSourceType: "json",
                autoGenerateColumns: bln,
                columns: [ columnVariable ],
                features: [
                    {
                        name: "Sorting",
                        type: "local",
                        applySortedColumnCss: false,
                        sortedColumnTooltip: "",
                        unsortedColumnTooltip: ""
                    }
                ]
            });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: My title should have probably been "How to create a reusable ig-grid function", since I wont be using the same grid, but the actual method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm embarrassed that I did not notice the columns is an array. 
Set the columns such as:

```
var carColumns =  [
    { key: "Make", headerText: "Make", dataType: "string", width: "34%" },
    { key: "Model", headerText: "Model", dataType: "string", width: "33%" },
    { key: "Year", headerText: "Year", dataType: "string", width: "33%"}
]

var dogColumns = [
    { key: "Type", headerText: "Type", dataType: "string", width: "50%" },
    { key: "Name", headerText: "Name", dataType: "string", width: "50%" }
]
```

Hope it helps someone out there.